# Simple probability problem. Why one method works and the other one doesn't?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I often have problems with 'simple' combinatorics and probability. For instance, I have the following problem:
We have a box with 10 balls. Three of them are red, two are green and five are white. I take two out without looking. What is the probability of the event $A = \{\text{The first ball is red or the second one is green.\}}$.
As the two events, $B=\{\text{the first ball is red\}}$ and $C=\{\text{the second ball is green\}}$  aren't independent, I need to get the probability of them separately and the probability of the intersection if $B$ and $C$.
I get it wrong already ad calculating the probabilities for $B$ and $C$.
My thinking was:
$$P(C) = \frac{\text{"good outcomes"}}{\text{"all possible outcomes"}}$$
For all outcomes I reasoned should be $10\cdot9$ as we can take any of the 10 balls as our first one and then any of the nine balls left as the second ball we take.
For the good outcomes: I have 10 possibilities for the first ball I take and then, if I already got the green one, then I should get the one green ball left. But if I haven't taken the green ball as the first one, I have still two to 'choose' from. So that would be $10\cdot 1 + 10\cdot 2$
Which gives me $P(C) = \frac{30}{90} = \frac{1}{3}$.

But I should've gotten $\frac{1}{5}$ which also makes sense if I think like this:
The good outcomes: $\frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{2}{9}$ (the first ball was red) + $\frac{5}{10}\cdot \frac{2}{9}$ (the first ball was white) + $\frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{9}$ (the first ball was green).
But in that case, I get $P(C) = \frac{1}{5}$

Can please, someone, explain to me where am I wrong?

Comment: I think you must have stated the problem wrong.  Did you mean to say, "={The first ball is red OR the second one is green.} ?"

Comment: Yes, I was going to say it too. It sounds it should be red OR green.

Comment: It is unclear to me what exactly you are wanting clarification on how to calculate, but if you are asking how to find the probability the second ball is green, it would simply be the same as the probability that the *first* ball was green, by symmetry, and would be $\frac{2}{10}$.  You could do this by breaking down into conditional probabilities... but why bother?  A simple combinatorial argument shows that they should be equal with no heavy calculation necessary.

Comment: As for $Pr(B\cap C)$ this expands by multiplication rule as $Pr(B\cap C)=Pr(B)\times Pr(C\mid B) = \frac{3}{10}\times\frac{2}{9}$, and for $Pr(B\cup C)$ by inclusion-exclusion and the previous result as $Pr(B)+Pr(C)-Pr(B\cap C)=\frac{3}{10}+\frac{2}{10}-\frac{3}{10}\times\frac{2}{9}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first method your $10$ should be the number that satisfies the color you specified.  If you say the first ball is green, there are only $2$ of those, so there are $2\cdot 1$ ways to pull the second ball green when the first is.  If the first ball is not green, there are only $8$ choices for the first ball, so $8 \cdot 2$ ways to have the second ball green when the first is not.  That gives $18$ total ways to have the second ball be green, and a probability of $\frac{18}{90}=\frac 15$

This has to be the same as having the first ball green, because you could draw the two balls and look at the second one first.  This is $\frac 2{10}=\frac 15$